# Full disk and SQL Server performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I have a server with 2 hard disks in it - each 400 GB. One hosts the the SQL Server files, the other one is used purely for backups. The backup disk fills up from time to time and I have to go in and delete old backups. I am no DBA so I am still trying to figure out a way to delete old backups automatically.

Can SQL Server perform slowly if the backup disk is almost full and has less than 100 MB space left on it; even though it doesn't have the database files on it only backups?

The first disk which holds the database files is never full.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a performance problem ('sql server performs poorly') so investigate it as a performance problem should be investiagted. Follow a methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). Follow the [Perforamnce Troubleshooting Flow Chart](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/presentations/archive/2008/04/18/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-and-scalability-flowchart.aspx). Stop making [guesses](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/31/the-bizzaro-guide-to-sql-server-performance/) and taking random actions. Measure.